# Using increment inside an if statement

Tags: c++11, if-statement, increment, control-flow

What is the difference between `if(++x < 0){something}` and `if(x + 1 < 0){something}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `++x` increments the value of `x` immediately by 1 and this new value of `x` is compared with `0`.

While `x+1` does not increment the value of `x` and it's original value remains the same, only the output of `x+1` is compared with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`++x` increases `x` by one and returns the result. `x + 1` leaves `x` as is and returns its value increased by one. So the difference is in the value of `x` after the operation.

The context (inside `if` condition or not) is irrelevant here.

Comment: So does this mean that for example, x = -1, if (++x < 0) means it is actually if (0 < 0) which will return false and x become 0. Where if (x + 1 < 0) will also return false, but x stays the same, 0?

Comment: In case of `x + 1` `x` will remain `-1`. Actually, you can test it yourself with Coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89891cb0c0cd6054